# How to scrape pdf to local folder with filename = url and delay within iteration?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, filenames

I scraped a website (`url =` "http://bla.com/bla/bla/bla/bla.txt") for all the **links** containing **.pdf** that were important to me.
These are now stored in `relative_paths`:

```
['http://aa.bb.ccc.com/dd/ee-fff/gg/hh99/iii/3333/jjjjj-99-0065.pdf',
 'http://aa.bb.ccc.com/dd/ee-fff/gg/hh99/iii/3333/jjjjj-99-1679.pdf',
 'http://aa.bb.ccc.com/dd/ee-fff/gg/hh99/iii/4444/jjjjj-99-9526.pdf',]
```

Now i want to **store the pdf "behind" the links in a local folder with their *filename* being their *url***.

None of the - although somewhat similar questions on the internet - seems to help me towards my goal. The closest i got was when it generated some weird file that didnt even have an extension. Here are some of the more promising code samples i already tried out.

```
for link in relative_paths:
    content = requests.get(link, verify = False)
    with open(link, 'wb') as pdf:
        pdf.write(content.content)

for link in relative_paths:  
    response = requests.get(url, verify = False)   
    with open(join(r'C:/Users/', basename(url)), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)

for link in relative_paths:
    filename = link
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(link, verify = False).content)

for link in relative_paths:
    pdf_response = requests.get(link, verify = False)
    filename = link
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf_response.content)
```

Now i am confused and dont know how to move forward. Can you transform one of the for loop and provide a small explanation, please? If the urls are too long for filename, a split at the 3rd last `/` is also ok. thanks :)

Also, i was asked by the website host to not scrape all of the pdfs at once so that the server does not get overloaded since there are thousands of pdfs behind the many links stored in `relative_paths`. That is why i am searching for a way to incorporate some sort of **delay** within my requests.

Comment: are all the file names unique? So can you split on the last `/` and keep only the `bla.pdf`, `bla1.pdf`, parts?

Comment: Yes, the URL are all unique from the 3rd last `/` onwards ('http://bla.com/bla**/**uniqe/unique/unique.pdf)
But i dont necessarily wanted to do so, as i would like to have the full URL when i parse the pdfs at a later stage. Because the pdfs themselves dont have their URL within them, i need to to it like this. I just said that because i assumed the URLs could be too many characters for a filename..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a shot:

```
import time
count_downloads = 25 #<--- wait x seconds after every 25 downloads
time_delay = 60 #<--- wait 60 seconds after every y downloads

for idx, link in enumerate(relative_paths):
    if idx % count_downloads == 0:
        print ('Waiting %s seconds...' %time_delay)
        time.sleep(time_delay)
    filename = link.split('jjjjj-')[-1] #<--whatever that is is where you want to split then
    
    try:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(link).content)
            print ('Saved: %s' %link)
    except Exception as ex:
         print('%s not saved. %s' %(link,ex))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Mostly. I set `count_downloads = 25`, `time_delay = 60` . But it would not download the pdfs in the specified interval. I had to abort the process mid-way because it downloaded without delay..

Comment: @id345678, ah. ya the `idx+1` needed to be in parentheses. I actually, just took out the `+1`. Also note, I had forgotten the `)`  in that first print statement. So fixed that as well. this should work now.

Comment: oh no worries. Ya good catch on that `)`. Well done! glad it works.

Comment: Oh yes, now the delay works, but the files arent saved. 

I get the error: "full_url.pdf not saved. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'characters_right_of_.com/.pdf"

Comment: would it be too much trouble to share a few items in the `relative_paths` list?

Comment: because of formatting reasons i will edit my original answer and add carefully designed examples of the `relative_paths` items. Beware that the number of letters (not numbers) is actually higher in the data, but i figured it would be easier to read. It should display which characters are unique and which not (especially the numerics). :)

Comment: Ok try it now. Let me know. If it works, I'll explain why you were getting the error.

Comment: actually i only care about the part to the right of jjjj

Comment: oh then you need to adapt the code to fit your need. Provided that part is always the same, it'll work. I commented it in the code

Comment: or to be more robust, use `filename = link.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: Ok, now it works perfect. I will try the more robust filename in a different scenario. For this, because the jjjjj part is always the same, it already works very good. I adjusted the time interval a little as 60 seconds is a little too much for the amount of pdfs i need, but again, thank you very much :)

Comment: oh sure. That's the point, to sort of give you the proof of concept and you can go and adjust to fit your needs. well done